# Temporarily set npm configuration 'audit-level' to 'critical'

Tags: npm, npm-audit

I'm currently running `npm audit` in a continuous integration setup. I would like to set the npm configuration setting `audit-level` to `critical` temporarily.

**Why?:** I would like npm audit to exit with the code `0` on low and medium and high vulnerabilities but still break on critical vulnerabilities.

See: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#audit-level

Comment: [audit-ci](https://github.com/IBM/audit-ci) may help.